# Force the max-height on an element which parent has no defined height without flexbox?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to force the `max-height` on an element which parent has *no defined* `height` without using the flexbox?

I am on a mobile view, and would like to put some overflow on **`modal-content`** element (! attention, *not on the parent* `modal-dialog`) in scrolling, when it exceeds the screen height (JsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/serhiol/rLtnz2n6/3/)):

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; right: 0; 
  left: 0; bottom: 0;
  max-height: 100vh;  
  background: lightblue;
}
.modal-header {font-size: 40px;}
.modal-dialog { margin: 10px; max-height: calc(100vh - 20px); background: yellow; }
.modal-content{ margin: 10px; 
font-size: 30px; overflow: auto; border: 1px red solid; background: rgba(255, 255, 204, 0.75);}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-header">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
    <div class="modal-content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you use jQuery or do you prefere a CSS trick?

Comment: Doesn't overflow auto/scroll work for this?

Comment: not on the **modal-content**, witch *height* is undefined, only on element which height is defined...( I need to scroll the modal-content, not modal-dialog...

Comment: So I am guessing you have other stuff in the dialog box so you cannot set any kind of height on your modal-content right?

Comment: @JoelBonetR: any solution, thanks ! I added a JSFiddle

Answer (score 1):

Just add overflow: auto to your modal-dialog:

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; right: 0; 
  left: 0; bottom: 0;
  max-height: 100vh;  
  background: lightblue;
}
.modal-dialog { margin: 10px; max-height: calc(100vh - 20px); background: yellow; overflow: auto; }
.modal-content{ margin: 10px; max-height: 100%;
font-size: 40px;border: 1px red solid; background: rgba(255, 255, 204, 0.75);}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that scrolling doesn't apply to `modal-content`, which height I try to set to 100%, but to `modal-dialog`, which height is defined.... I need to apply it to the content...

Answer (score 0):

Here it's a solution with jQuery, it can be adapted to wherever you need.

It simply reads the screen height and apply the same height to the modal.
Then an overflow scroll is added to .modal (this can be declared on the CSS directly instead of doing it on the jQuery).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var height = $(window).height();
$('.modal').height(height);
$('.modal').css('overflow', 'scroll');

});
```

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; right: 0; 
  left: 0; bottom: 0;
  max-height: 100vh;  
  background: lightblue;
}
.modal-header {font-size: 40px;}
.modal-dialog { margin: 10px; max-height: calc(100vh - 20px); background: yellow; }
.modal-content{ margin: 10px; 
font-size: 30px; overflow: auto; border: 1px red solid; background: rgba(255, 255, 204, 0.75);}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-header">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
    <div class="modal-content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The blue color marks where the screen ends, then you've the modal overflowing. If you don't want this blue color to be shown, you can change

```
$('.modal').height(height);
```

to

```
$('.modal').css('min-height', height);
```

and it should do the trick.
It's also used to make screen-height page blocks.